# Understanding example code of ambiguity resolution

Tags: c++

The following codes are quoted from C++11 standard N3485 Section 6.8.3 about ambiguity resolution:

```
struct T1 {
   T1 operator()(int x) 
   { 
        return T1(x); 
   }
   int operator=(int x) 
   { 
       return x; 
   }
   T1(int) { }
};
struct T2 
{ 
    T2(int){ } 
};

int a, (*(*b)(T2))(int), c, d;

void f() {
    // disambiguation requires this to be parsed as a declaration:
    T1(a) = 3,
    T2(4),                   // T2 will be declared as
    (*(*b)(T2(c)))(int(d)); // a variable of type T1
                            // but this will not allow
                            // the last part of the
                            // declaration to parse
                            // properly since it depends
                            // on T2 being a type-name
}
```

I have no idea about how to parse this code:

```
 T1(a) = 3,
        T2(4),                  
        (*(*b)(T2(c)))(int(d));
```

**What does it mean in this case?** Could you explain it to me? This example code seems rather obscure to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at:  http://cdecl.org/

Comment: The example is obscure, but you can find less obscure examples that also fall in the same category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that when something can be parsed as a declaration, it should be parsed as a declaration. In this case,

```
T1(a) = 3
```

Is a valid declaration, and it declares an object `a` of type `T1`, initialized from the value `3` (rather than constructing a temporary of type `T1` initialized from `a`, then assigning `3` to that temporary). This is, in fact, equivalent to the following:

```
T1 a = 3
```

Now the remaining declarators:

```
T2(4)
```

Here `T2` is the name of an object of type `T1` initialized from the value `4`, as in:

```
T1 a = 3, T2(4)
```

So `T2` is the name *of the object*, not of a type, similarly to the case below:

```
int x = 42, y(1729)
```

Where `x` is an object of type `int` initialized from `42`, and `y` is another object of type `int` initialized from the value `1729`.

Then the last declarator cannot be parsed correctly, because `T2` is not the name of a type, but the name of an object.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, Andy. But how may I understand this `(*(*b)(T2(c)))(int(d));`?

Comment: @taocp: You're welcome :) You may not understand that as anything, since `T2` is not the name of a type (because of the previous declaration). That's what the example is about

Comment: One of the best interpretations I've ever seen.

Comment: @SChepurin: Glad you found it helpful :)

Comment: @Andy Prowl OK, that looks really weird to me, I don't even know how to read it out. So you mean because it is not a valid thing, so I should simply ignore about it?

Comment: @taocp: Well, in a sense yes, `T2` is not the name of a type, which means you (or the compiler) cannot make sense out of it. As an exercise, you may try parsing it pretending that `T2` is a type, and that should make more sense ;)